# How to handle entity form selection in collection field : Symfony

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I want to use multiple 'entity' fields as collection field type :

```
class AddBrand extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('Name', 'text', array('label' => 'Enter brand name'))
            ->add('Models', 'collection', array
            (
                'type' => 'entity',
                'options' => array
                (
                    'class' => 'Baka\MainBundle\Entity\Model',
                    'choice_label' => 'Name'
                )
            ));
    }
```

But I cant find out if its possible to specify that 'entity' field options (if no options are specified the '*The required option "class" is missing*' exception is being thrown). Brand is in OneToMany relation with Model.